# Power off external disk in Ubuntu, then turn it back on remotely without rebooting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, external-hard-drive, power-management

I am remotely managing an Ubuntu 20.04 host that has an external drive attached to it. I am not using the drive very often and I am powering it down to preserve its lifetime (as shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1138498/turn-off-spin-down-external-usb-hdd-on-linux)). However after powering it off, the external drive "disappears" from the Disks management window, and there is no way to power it back on unless a) someone disconnects and reconnects the USB cable or b) the system is rebooted (which I do not want to do for other reasons).

Is there a way to power on the external USB drive again remotely and without rebooting?

Comment: Until you find an answer that reverts `udisksctl power-off`, consider `umount` + `hdparm -Y` (or at least `hdparm -y`). See `man 8 hdparm`. The linked question actually mentions `hdparm -Y` but the command doesn't work for the asker there. Does it work for you? Experiment with some local disk(s) maybe to feel (and hear) the difference, to decide if it's worth it; and to know quirks if any (e.g. in my tests the very first read after `hdparm -Y` throws I/O error, but the drive gets awoken and I can use it eventually).

Comment: I'm getting the following: `sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
 issuing sleep command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
`

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that turning a hard drive off lengthens its life. If you cannot restart the machine to restart the drive, then just leave it running.

A good hard drive can run non-stop without harm or seriously shortening its life.

So it is a trade off:

Restart the machine when needed and turn off the drive (rarely used you said),  or

Leave the drive running as that will not seriously harm it.

Comment: It is true that spin-ups also decrease the hard drive's lifetime along with total power on time. It ultimately depends on how frequent you spin up your drive. However "leaving it running" does also affect the drive's lifetime. Nevertheless, I just want to know if you can power-up the external drive remotely without rebooting, this does not answer my question

Comment: The only way I know to do what you is to restart the computer.  My experience is that drives running all the time do not suffer experience significant lifetime loss. I see that at a lot of customers.