# How to poweroff safely for HDD? Arch Linux

Tags: hard-drive, arch-linux, configure

I use Arch Linux on the external pocket (HDD). When I poweroff my pc, HDD clicks because it stops immediately. How can I configure safely poweroff for my HDD?

I tried to configure APM using hdparm, but it didn't work, HDD clicks

Comment: the HDD's click is probably the read/write head being "parked" - it's what is supposed to happen

Comment: @JaromandaX, but if i use safely drive pull out, like on the windows, it stops gently, without notice.

Comment: What if you power off windows?

Comment: `I tried to configure APM using hdparm` - what did you actually do?

Comment: @JaromandaX, HDD gently stops.

Comment: @JaromandaX, sudo hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda

Comment: how about `udiskctl` as mentioned in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1138498/turn-off-spin-down-external-usb-hdd-on-linux) - you may want to run that in a script as part of the shutdown procedure - this is easily achieved in systemd, [for example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown)

Comment: by the way, a value of 128 to 254 do NOT permit spin-down, so, you picked a bad value to start with, though `hdparm` won't help spinning down the HDD on demand, that's what `udisksctl` is used for (note the misspelling in my previous comment)

Comment: @JaromandaX, i can't poweroff drive using `udisksctl` because my Arch system is on this drive, drive in use.

Comment: ahhh, that's why it behaves differently in windows vs linux ... in windows, it can be spun down before poweroff, in linux it can not, obviously. So, refer to my first comment. i.e. there is absolutely nothing wrong with the click

Comment: @JaromandaX, but power just simply been cutted, no slowing down. It can be harmful to HDD.

Comment: you can't "slow down power" *It can be harmful to HDD* - cite your source for this information

Comment: Ok you're right, thanks for answering